# call a php function or file from a HTML input button

Tags: php, function, class, button

What is the best way to implement php code to run when
a button is pressed/clicked. Done some research but couldn't find anything relevant apart of few examples that show use of JavaScript.
I want it to be purely in PHP.
At this precise moment I have created the buttons in the following way `<input type='button' value='Click Me'/>` now not sure what to do. Could anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type='button' name='btn_func' value='Click Me'/>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['btn_func'])){
        //call the function here.
    }
?>
```

If you have 10 buttons:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type='button' name='btn_func_1' value='Click Me 1'/>
    <input type='button' name='btn_func_2' value='Click Me 2'/>
    <input type='button' name='btn_func_3' value='Click Me 3'/>
    <input type='button' name='btn_func_4' value='Click Me 4'/>
    <input type='button' name='btn_func_5' value='Click Me 5'/>
    <input type='button' name='btn_func_6' value='Click Me 6'/>
    <input type='button' name='btn_func_7' value='Click Me 7'/>
    <input type='button' name='btn_func_8' value='Click Me 8'/>
    <input type='button' name='btn_func_9' value='Click Me 9'/>
    <input type='button' name='btn_func_10' value='Click Me 10'/>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['btn_func_1'])){
        //call the function here.
    }
?>
```

Or use a Conditional/Switch statement.

Comment: @gabmon I have got about 10 buttons, does that mean I have to put each of them in a different form like you have done?

Comment: Thank you, I think now I have a clue how I am going to implemented it. Gracies

Comment: @Jordan please check or voteup if we answered your questions.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run a PHP script by native HTML only. Using JavaScript would be the simplest solution you can do.

Answer (score 0):

The basics of a form and php. when the button is pushed, the form calls an action (some page, even itself). Then the php checks if the button was pushed. If so, do something, if not, ignore it. Instead of creating a button though, a submit would work better, but the button works just fine.

```
<form method="post" action="./PHPScripts.php" />
     <input type='button' value='Click Me' name='button' /> <-- added a name
     <input type='submit' value='Click Me' name='submitButton' />
     <input type='submit' value='Click Me' name='submitButton2' />
</form>


// below would be on the page called by the action in the above form
// which can be on the same page with no problem, but larger amounts of
// code become more difficult to read, so having multiple files is recommended
<?php
     if($_POST['button']) {
        // php code (either execute it, or call function)
     }
     if($_POST['submitButton']) {
        // php code (either execute it, or call function)
     }
     if($_POST['submitButton2']) {
        // php code (either execute it, or call function)
     }
?>
```

It's best to keep php code on top of html if on same page, but for demonstration reasons, I've put it on the bottom. (Easier to read)

Comment: if happy and have no more questions on this topic, feel free to mark one of our answers as accepted that way anyone else looking for an answer on this subject can see that this has been answered,

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `input type="button"`, I am assuming you will need JavaScript to handle the click event? Then make an Ajax request to a PHP file or something?

Or, you could change your input type from "button" to "submit" `<input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />`

Then the...easiest (for lack of better words) is to check at the top of your page for the submit post variable. If it's there, PHP will handle it. Or, it will display the form if the variable is not set.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitButton']))
    {
        // form has been submitted.
        // do something with PHP.

    }
?>
<form action="file.php" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is, you will need to give the button the **name** attribute. Depending on how the form, is then submitted, in this case, to itself or to another page determined by the form **action** attribute and the method, the script will then run.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post"> 
<input type='button' value='Click Me' **name="submit"**/> 
</form>

if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
     //runs when the button is clicked
}
```